# How to call bootstrap modal in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to call a modal that I have in a html file which is hidden alongside another modal. One of them appears as the button is clicked but the other one is to be called by php as part of a verification process.

Here is my php code:

```
$File = include("index2.html");
$Msg = 'Welcome ';
$search=$_POST['search'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE IDs LIKE '%$search%'  LIMIT 0 , 10"); //OR author LIKE '%$search%'
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
// Display search result
         if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
                 echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                                 echo 'alert("Verification Complete");';
                                  echo '</script>';



            while ($results = $query->fetch()) {

                $Studname = $results['Studentname'];


                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';                
                echo 'alert("'.$Msg.$Studname.'")';
                echo '</script>';



               echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
               echo '$(File).ready(function() {';
               echo '$("#myAdvert").modal("show");';
               echo '});';
               echo '</script>';

            }

         } else {
           echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Sorry your ID was not found");';
            echo 'window.location.href = "/Koleesy/index.html";';
            echo '</script>';
        }
?>
```

After the user is welcomed I want the hidden modal from my index.html to be called so the user can continue submitting the advert.
I've tried using the include function but that doesn't seem to work in my favor.
How do I do this? 
Every answer is appreciated.

Comment: Where is your modal box defined?

Comment: It's in my main index file, on the home page. I named that index2 because the php couldn't find the main one so I duplicated it and threw the index2 into the folder with the php.

Comment: Just a suggestion, instead of writing lots of echo statements you can do something like <?php if(true){?>  <div>your html code goes here</div> <?php }  ?> this would make your code more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'll definitely use that. Its quite messy with all the echos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myAdvert').modal('show');
});
</script>";
```